# Log file for AWS SES

Tags: aws-ses

For sending emails we moved from Mailjet (too many bounces, blacklisted) to Amazon SES. Seems to work fine with a free tier.
But we miss a detailed log with status information (sent, delivered, soft bounced, hard bounced...) about each email.
Can we have that in AWS without relevant costs?